# Can not execute connection to Postgres via Jenkins Groovy

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-scriptler

Using Scriptler can not connect to Postgresql via Jenkins groovy, neither via executing psql command, nor via using jdbc:

1. psql

```
command = """
        PGPASSWORD=1111\
        psql -h xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com\
        -U master -d yyy -c "select * from table"
        """
proc =  command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
return proc.in.text
```

I receive the error

> Cannot run program "PGPASSWORD=1111": error=2, No such file or directory

2. jdbc

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def dbUrl      = "jdbc:postgresql://xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com/yyy"
def dbUser     = "master"
def dbPassword = "1111"
def dbDriver   = "org.postgresql.jdbcDriver"
def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)
```

it returns

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.jdbcDriver

I installed plugins `database`, `PostgreSQL API Plugin` & `database-postgresql`. Jenkins v.2.176.1

Answer (score 0):

So your first attempt via command.execute() will not work because you are trying to use shell command syntax and you're not running a shell.

The 2nd one will not work because you have to tell Groovy where to find the postgress jdbc library.  You may be able to do this with Groovy Grape.

Personally I would do psql command using a shell step.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "you are trying to use shell command syntax and you're not running a shell"? I have another similar executions within shell, like
` def command = "aws ecr list-images"` and `def proc = "git ls-remote -h ${gitURL}".execute()` They run with success

Comment: In the above command, the string substituion (for gitURL) is happening in Groovy.  I'm assuming the psql command will look for a PGPASSWORD environment varaible.  In order to set this you need to create a shell script and execute that, so the command would be 'sh -c ....'. In which case you can use a shell step which would be easier